# mp4 is hanging, using blender created mp4

Tags: mp4, blender-2.61

ok, this is an issue, that might be a problem of video-js or a render problem of blender V2.67
I start with asking you ;-)

- I just wanted to try video-js and decided to create some simple video with blender (win7, file format mpeg) in order to have some demo video.
- using  vlc and media player directly showed a working video
- using it with :    
  shows the frame with poster and start button in a correct way
- pushing the button doesn't change the view, but adds a "waiting animation" as dots, turning in a circle
- nothing else happens

Using an ogg rendering of blender instead: works fine.
It means, code and swf of video.js are fine so far

Any ideas?

If useful, i may send the demo video for further investigations and place the link over here. Just tell me and i will do so until tomorrow

Comment: sorry didn't recognize, that my html was filtered

Comment: ok, couldn't add code nore an image of it. Another try with actual chrome shows the same effect